# CORS withCredentials - support limited?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cors

I've noticed that certain browsers do not seem to support withCredentials in CORS requests, at least under some conditions. Specifically, in IE 10, attempting to set `xhr.withCredentials = true` results in:

`SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError`

and in Safari 5 (but not 6) I get

`INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`

again, in response to the same statement.

Are these known problems, or am I setting up my XHR wrong somehow? Is there a list of which browsers support `withCredentials`?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=cors

Comment: Are you setting `withCredentials` after `open` but before `send`?

Comment: Acording to [the `withCredentials` spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute): "*When set: throws an `InvalidStateError` exception if the state is not `UNSENT` or `OPENED`, or if the `send()` flag is set.*" This suggests that it must bet before calling `send()`. Some browsers might be erroneously more strict than this specification rule, however. Can you post your actual code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [August 16, 2011 XHR draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20110816/#the-withcredentials-attribute) specifies a rule for setting `withCredentials`:

> When set: throws an `INVALID_STATE_ERR` exception if the state is not OPENED or if the `send()` flag is true.

However, the [January 17, 2012 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/) is more permissive:

> When set: throws an `InvalidStateError` exception if the state is not UNSENT or OPENED, or if the `send()` flag is set.

You are probably setting `withCredentials` before calling `.open`, which is disallowed by the 2011 spec but allowed by the 2012 spec. To comply with both, simply move your property assignment after your call to `.open`.